# Given a datetime.time(X,Y) object, how to convert it to time string?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am given the following object:

```
datetime.time(18, 50)
```

I want to convert to a string:

```
"18:50:00"
```

Please advise how can I do this?

Tried `strftime` but getting errors.

```
datetime.time(18, 50).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
from datetime import time
print(time(18, 50).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Importing the [time function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) from datetime module seems to be different from [datetime instance's time method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time).